# How to create a JavaScript function which identifies specific options in a html <select> tag?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-select, innerhtml

Currently assigned the task of creating a website which uses python to visualize a network. With this, after clicking a button, the python script will run off of specific parameters the user sets. Although, I am struggling to figure out how to communicate those parameters to the python script. To call the python script we are using PHP, and my friend suggested that when we call the shell script, we can put in specific commands, changing the parameters of the python script. So we came up with the idea of using JavaScript functions, to change the HTML when a user changes different parameters. The only issue is, its either not possible, or I wrote the code completely wrong. Any help is great!

JavaScript I have tried:

```
// Function for amount of samples

let amountSamples = function() {

  var selectAmountSamples = document.getElementById('amountSamples').value;
  var samples = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", ];
  var text = "";
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
    if (selectAmountSamples == "1") {
      text += samples[i];
    } else if (selectAmountSamples == "5") {
      alert('5');
    } else {
      alert('broken');
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("amountSamples").innerHTML = text;

}
```

PHP code to call the python script:

```
   <?php
   if (isset($_GET["run"])) {
      $output = shell_exec('sh test.sh');
      echo "<pre>$output</pre> works";
    }
   ?>
```

If there is a more efficient way to call upon this script, I would be very interested in knowing how.

---

HTML code for selecting types:

```
<li>
           <p id="amountSamples">Select your amount of samples:</p>
      </li>
      <li> <select name="Number of Samples" class="select" 
            id="amountSamples" oninput="amountSamples()">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
           </select> 
       </li>
```

I expect the output to give some type of indication telling us when a specific value is selected.